# Unable to join to domain

Tags: domain-controller

I have deployed two EC2 instances on AWS with one as a DC role and the other as a sql server which I intend to join to the domain.

However when I try to join it I am getting the following error.

NetSetup.log

```
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 ----------------------------------------------------------------

-
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'SQL' is valid as type 1 name
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 NetpCheckNetBiosNameNotInUse for 'SQL' [MACHINE] returned 0x0
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 NetpValidateName: name 'SQL' is valid for type 1
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 -----------------------------------------------------------------
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'sql' is valid as type 5 name
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 NetpValidateName: name 'sql' is valid for type 5
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 -----------------------------------------------------------------
01/27/2023 00:12:04:860 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'demo.local' is valid as type 3 name
01/27/2023 00:12:19:872 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid for demo.local returned 0x54b, last error is 0x0
01/27/2023 00:12:19:872 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'demo.local' returned 0x54b
```

dcdiag.log shows

```
DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "demo.local":

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.demo.local

The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
dc.demo.local


However no domain controllers could be contacted.

Common causes of this error include:

- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.

- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
```

When I run the following command from the sql server I see

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nltest /dsgetdc:demo.local /force
Getting DC name failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN
```

Port query from sql to DC shows the following

```
C:\Users\Administrator>portqry -n xx.xx.xx.xx -e 53 -p both

Querying target system called:

 xx.xx.xx.xx

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...


IP address resolved to dc.demo.local

querying...

TCP port 53 (domain service): LISTENING

UDP port 53 (domain service): LISTENING
```

It's a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter edition for DC and SQL.

Comment: Is the SQL server using the DC as its DNS server?

Comment: yes it is using the DC as its DNS Server.

Comment: From the SQL server, show the full results of "nslookup demo.local"

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup demo.local
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  xx.xx.0.128

Name:    demo.local
Address:  xx.xx.0.128

Comment: I do have a host file hack in sql.